# Error in keras model for classification model with transformers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I followed this tutorial:
https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/
For classification model with transformers to my time-series.
However, in the line:

```
x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
        )(x, x)
```

I get the error:

```
{IndexError}tuple index out of range
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: @okuoub Is it possible to provide some dummy data that can reproduce your above error?

Comment: @M.Innat This is the same code from the tutorial so data is taken from root_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hfawaz/cd-diagram/master/FordA/" , but I think it doens matter since the error is in building the architecture - before the fit

Comment: @okuoub are you able to run the above official code example?

Comment: @M.Innat No, when I paste it to my pycharm I get the above error

Comment: Can you run it on colab properly and not on your local system? If so, what's your TensorFlow version?

Comment: @okuoub can you give more context about your error? which python and tensorflow version are you running? does this happens while fitting the model?

Comment: This question is a joke in its current state. There is no way to reproduce it.

Comment: @okuoub Can you please add output of `pandas.show_versions()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I came here for the bounty, then I tried on Colab and everything worked fine..

[image]

Next I read the comments: "*This question is a joke in its current state. There is no way to reproduce it.*" and at this point I agree. But as I am a *Hans in Luck* and obviously have to much time procrastinating, I started Pycharm following the OPs cue: "*No, when I paste it to my pycharm I get the above error*"

But this also worked for me, which makes me wonder whether you have touched something,  so I am happy to provide a(n) (untouched) working version for you..

```
import numpy as np

def readucr(filename):
    data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter="\t")
    y = data[:, 0]
    x = data[:, 1:]
    return x, y.astype(int)


root_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hfawaz/cd-diagram/master/FordA/"

x_train, y_train = readucr(root_url + "FordA_TRAIN.tsv")
x_test, y_test = readucr(root_url + "FordA_TEST.tsv")

x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

n_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))

idx = np.random.permutation(len(x_train))
x_train = x_train[idx]
y_train = y_train[idx]

y_train[y_train == -1] = 0
y_test[y_test == -1] = 0


from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Normalization and Attention
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(x, x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    return x + res
```

Also to make sure that we are talking of the same package versions

**I used numpy (1.21.2) and tensorflow (2.6.0) - try with these versions or let me know in case you used different versions.**